# Как написать модульный тест для приложения на Go?

Tags: golang, тестирование, юнит-тесты

Например, есть простая функция:

```
func add(x, y int) int {
    return x + y
}
```

Какие есть встроенные средства, позволяющие ее оттестировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть команда gotest. Для пакета sample запуск команды gotest вернет PASS - тест пройдет.

Файл sample.go:

```
package sample

func Add(x, y int) int {
    return x + y
}
```

Файл sample_test.go:

```
package sample

import "testing"

func TestAdd(t *testing.T) {
    var x, y, z int = 1, 2, 3

    if z != Add(x, y) {
        t.Errorf("%d != %d", z, x + y)
    }
}
```

Файл Makefile:

```
include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.inc

TARG=sample
GOFILES=sample.go

include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.pkg
```